# Add checkbox field with catalog category

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I am trying to add a checkbox field with catalog category with following code but its not adding with category, when i change to text it works properly but not with checkbox .

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'disable_banner',  array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'Disable Banner',
    'input'    => 'checkbox',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0
));
```

I found lots of tutorials for text fields but not for checkbox or radio button.
Is it possible to add checkbox through custom module and if yes then what i am missing here.

Here is the tutorial I use for reference https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: I added this and now i can see test field under general tab ( extra added ), how can I move this for general information tab and change lable to Disable banner. I tried with updateattribute in upgrade file but its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "test",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "test",
    "input"    => "checkbox",
    "class"    => "",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "0",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,

    "visible_on_front"  => false,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));
$installer->endSetup();
```

[image]

**EDIT**

For update exciting category attribute. File name like mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php first 0.0.1 is current config.xml version and 0.0.2 new config.xml version

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category','test','label', 'Disable banner');

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Comment: I added this and now i can see test field under general tab ( extra added ), how can I move this for general information tab and change lable to Disable banner. I tried with updateattribute in upgrade file but its not working

Comment: Update answer check it